# First order differential equations $\frac{dy}{dx}=1-y^2$

Tags: calculus

$\frac{dy}{dx}=1-y^2$

My answer was

$\frac{\ln(y+1)+\ln(1-y)}{2}+C$

But the textbook got

$\frac{\ln(\frac{1+y}{1-y})}{2}=x+C$

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Where is $x$ and $=$ in your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a $x$ and your integral on the left-hand side is not correct

$$dy/(1-y^2)=dx \implies \dfrac{1}{2}\left[\ln(1+y)-\ln(1-y) \right]+C=x$$

$$\implies \dfrac{\ln \dfrac{1+y}{1-y}}{2}=x+(-C)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I suppose that your mistake is , after the partial fractions decomposition $$\frac{1}{1-y^2 }=\frac{1}{2(1-y)}+\frac{1}{2(1+y)}$$
in the calculation of the integral
$$
I=\int \frac{1}{2(1-y)}dy
$$
that, with the substitution $$1-y=t  \qquad -dy=dt$$  becomes
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{t}(-dt)=-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{t}(dt)
$$